# Crash recovery for Safari

Tags: safari

I lose my tabs when Safari crashes. Is there any way to recover them? Firefox, Opera and Chrome all have this enabled by default, but Safari doesn't seem to have this ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The History menu has the option "Reopen All Windows from Last Session."

I prefer the plugin [Saft](http://haoli.dnsalias.com/Saft/), which among other things does this automatically, and it even works after Safari crashes.

By the way, the most likely cause of crashes in Safari is Flash, so using [Click to Flash](http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/) will cut down on Safari crashes significantly.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an AUTOMATIC and configurable RESTORE Extension that takes less then a minute to install.
[SafariRestore](http://sweetpproductions.com/extensions/extensions.htm) - what a reasonable name. It's donation ware. You may also go to safari extension gallery to browse more apps, you get there by selection of "Safari Extension Gallery" tag under the safari menu located at the left top of your screen... click safari, it's under 'about safari.